# How to count execution time of the observable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am looking for solution to measure the execution of some task

1. I want to start timer in some place
2. I want to execute some task
3. In different part of code i want to be able to stop timer i get the execution final execution time result

I guess this can be really similiar to use EventBus to post event of starting counting and stoping.

So i can have a function:

```
doSomething(){
//start counting
}
```

in ohter function i want to have access to the counter and invoke stop on it:

```
otherFunctionWhichCanBeInvokedLater(){
//stop counter and get the duration time
}
```

Is there nice way to acomplish this in Rx?
I want to use Kotlin and RxJava2 for this.

Answer (score 0):

how about using the `doOnXXX` hooks, like so:

```
fun startTimer() {
    //start counting
}

fun stopTimer() {
    //stop counter and get the duration time
}

fun observe() {
    Observable.just(...)
            .doOnSubscribe { startTimer() }
            .doFinally { stopTimer() }
            .subscribeBy(...)
}
```

depending on your requirements, you could replace `doOnFinally` with a setup that uses `doOnComplete` and/or `doOnError`.